# clang - how to disable [-Werror,-Wpointer-bool-conversion]

Tags: clang, warnings

I want to compile a project with clang, and got some errors like
error: [-Werror,-Wpointer-bool-conversion]

1. I didn't set -Wpointer-bool-conversion as error, does clang do it by default?
2. How to turn off this error, treat it as normal warning, I don't want to break the compiling with this warning.
3. If I add -Wno-pointer-bool-conversion, then the error is gone, also the warning, I want to keep the warning.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-Wno-error=pointer-bool-conversion will resolve my problem

Comment: I found out the hard way that this is LLVM specific and does not apply to GCC. The following resources might come handy https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html any pointers to better resources most welcome